# form validation javascript (error message showed and disappeared quickly)

Tags: javascript, forms

i want to show the error messages next to the input element and if there's no error messages then send the data to the server (clear data from form) so fire the function on submit

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPNpNw

the problem is the error messages showed and disappeared quickly (blink)

but when change the input type to button

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjaZqe

will work but the data will be still in form and not cleared as input type="submit" will do

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>     </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>

          <table style="width:50%;">
            <tr>
                <td>first name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="txtfname" /></td>
                <td><span id="error"></span></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>age</td>
                <td><input type="number" id="txtage" onblur="checkAge(txtage)" /></td>      
                <td><span id="errorage"></span></td>
             </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td>user name</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="txtuser" /></td>
                  <td><span id="erroruser"></span></td>
              </tr>





              <tr>
                  <td>country</td>
                  <td>
                      <select onselect="checkSelect(this)" id="slct">
                          <option selected="selected" value="default">select your country</option>
                          <option>egypt</option>
                          <option>usa</option>

                      </select>
                  </td>
                  <td><span id="errorslct"></span></td>

              </tr>


              <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><input type="submit" value="register" onclick="allvalidate()" /></td>

              </tr>
            </table>





        </form>





        <script>

            function allvalidate() {
                validate();
                checkAge(txtage);
                checkuser(txtuser);
                checkSelect(this);
            }


                  function validate() {
                      var txtf = document.getElementById('txtfname');
                      if (txtf.value == 0 || txtf.value == null) {
                          document.getElementById('error').innerText = ('you must enter firstname');
                          document.getElementById('error').style.color = 'red';
                          txtf.focus();
                          return false;
                      }
                      else {
                          document.getElementById('error').innerText = ('');
                          //return true;
                      }


                  }

                function checkAge(input) {
                    if (input.value < 18 || input.value > 70) {
                        document.getElementById('errorage').innerText = ('age must be from 18 :70');
                        document.getElementById('errorage').style.color = 'red';
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('errorage').innerText = ('');
                        return true;
                    }

                }

                function checkuser(input) {
                    var pattern = '^[a-zA-Z]+$';
                    if (input.value.match(pattern)) {
                        document.getElementById('erroruser').innerText = '';
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('erroruser').innerText = ('enter valid email');
                        document.getElementById('erroruser').style.color = 'red';

                        return false;
                    }


                }

                function checkSelect() {
                    var select=document.getElementById('slct')
                    if (select.value=='default') {
                        document.getElementById('errorslct').innerText = ('you must choose country');
                        document.getElementById('errorslct').style.color = 'red';

                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById('errorslct').innerText = '';

                        return true;
                    }


                }




        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<td><input type="submit" value="register" onclick="allvalidate()" /></td>
```

To:

```
<td><input type="submit" value="register" onclick="return allvalidate()" /></td>
```

Otherwise the boolean value is discarded. You also need to change `allvalidate` to actually return `false` if one of the validations fail:

```
function allvalidate() {
    var validated = true;

    if (!validate()) validated = false;
    if (!checkAge(txtage)) validated = false;
    if (!checkuser(txtuser)) validated = false;
    if (!checkSelect(this)) validated = false;

    return validated;
}
```

Comment: the problem is still when click on the button
the error massages blinks quickly ( show and hide) - as a behavior to submit as i thought @Overv

Comment: yeah it works there as input type button ,so the data will be still in form not sent

Comment: @user4833581 No, it says `input type="submit`.

Comment: yeah ,thanks for your effort but in this pen the data not cleared too after send valid data and i know that the input type is submit and i really didn't know why this strange bahviour , i want to post an image to declare more but this is my first quesion there so i couldn't post imgs @Overv

Comment: @user4833581 You need to uncomment `return true` in the `validate()` function, then it works. Otherwise it will return `undefined`, which has the same effect as `false` here.

Comment: i very appreciate your help and thanks for your good eye to see the comment code ( i used comment to test different cases to know where the error and i forget to un comment one of 'm ) thanks ,agian 
but to make sure that i fully undrstand the case your soultion was to make the function return true so send the data to server in case of it was a valid data @Overv

Comment: @user4833581 Yes, but more importantly to return false when the data is not valid (that's what actually stops submitting).

Comment: thanks , if u can explain why use return word when we call a function make a difference
onclick="return allvalidate()"
vs
onclick="allvalidate()"

becuase i really didn't know the difference but when replace it with each other the result changed 
@Overv

Comment: If you don't include return, nothing is done with the true or false value. You need to return it in onclick to tell the browser to not submit.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><input type="submit" value="register" onclick="allvalidate()" /></td>

          </tr>
```

well, I'm not expert but what I think is that data is not sending, you need to call the function on onsubmit event, instead of calling it on onclick event. It would send the data as well.